# Spring Security REST authorization

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security, restful-authentication

I'm tired to find how I can login by Spring Security REST json. I write backend for Android/iOS.Here is my **security.xml:**

```
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">        
        <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />      
        <custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>  
        <logout />               
    </http> 

    <beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
          <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
          <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="mySuccessHandler"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="com.teamodc.jee.webmail.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />   
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager> 

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

This is my **AuthenticationController:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/auth")
public class AuthorizationController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier(value = "authenticationManager")
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private SimpleGrantedAuthority anonymousRole = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ANONYMOUS");

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Accept=application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, String> login(@RequestParam("login") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {
        Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();


            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

            try {
                Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(token);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);

                response.put("status", "true");             
                return response;
            } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
                System.out.println("Login 3");
                response.put("status", "false");
                response.put("error", "Bad credentials");
                return response;
            }
        }
```

And finally, my **web.xml:**

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/dispatcher.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>charsetFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>   

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I have tested it from Firefox rest client, but when I set the URL is bla/user/1 then it took me 401 (it's right), but when URL is bla/auth/login it took me 404, and return WARN [org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - 
But how it can be when I marked path in @Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `login()` method seems to be mapped to `/auth/auth/login`. The path given on the method level `@RequestMapping` annotation is relative to that of the class level annotation.

Try changing the method level annotation to `@RequestMapping(value = "/login"...`.

**Edit:**
If that was just a typo, and you still have problems with handler mapping, then make sure that you have the appropriate instructions in your spring context:

1. `<context:component-scan base-package="package.for.controllers"/>` in order to have your controllers instantiated as spring beans.
2. `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` in order to have support for `@RequestMapping` annotated controller methods. See the [reference docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-enable) for more info.

Also, make sure these are actually in the same context (normally in servlet context).

Comment: No, that was a mistake, when I copy paste to here. My question is still actual.

Comment: Thanx, I've checked my packages and it was name wrong. Now I have 400 Bad request.

Comment: Anyway, HTTP 400 (Bad request) is typically caused by a missing request parameter. Check if you post both `login`, and `password` as requested by the handler method. Enable trace level logging on `org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod` to see if that's really the cause of the problem.